# Make image with C# (Grid table)

Tags: c#, image, button, printing

I have 100 buttons, Now I want to print them in paper or output like image.
I don't work with C# print and image at all.

Now I need simple printable output.

Note: I have two dimensional array of int

```
private int[,] map = new int[10,10];
```

and where cell contain "X" I have value 1.

http://p30up.ir/images/1wddsvsm7i4z5idzr6r.gif

http://p30up.ir/images/vvz5nnbe79u81p2ap6rp.jpg

Comment: can you make your question clear?

Comment: Are you using WinForms? WPF?

Comment: WinForms, Just printing buttons